# How to override default shipment pdf styling file in magento2.2.7

Tags: magento2

I want to change the shipment pdf font family how to do that in magento2

Answer (score 0):

Override `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf` class. Because there are some "hard code" functions to set fonts for Pdf like.

```
protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
{
}
```

So try with below way.

**Using plugin way**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf">
       <plugin name="add_font_to_pdf" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\AddFontToPdf" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/AddFontToPdf.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class AddFontToPdf
{
    public function beforeDrawLineBlocks($subject, $page, array $draw, array $pageSettings = [])
    {
        $newDraw = $draw;
        // Update the $draw array to add your font
        return [$page, $newDraw, $pageSettings];
    }

}
```

---

**Using Prefrance way**

> app/Code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment" type="Namespace\Modulename\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment"/>
</config>
```

> Namespace\Modulename\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf;

/**
 * Sales Order Shipment PDF model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Shipment extends AbstractPdf
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface
     */
    protected $_localeResolver;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param Config $pdfConfig
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_localeResolver = $localeResolver;
        parent::__construct(
            $paymentData,
            $string,
            $scopeConfig,
            $filesystem,
            $pdfConfig,
            $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $inlineTranslation,
            $addressRenderer,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Draw table header for product items
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath($column['font_file']);
        $page->setFont($font, $fontSize);
        //Do your stuff.
    }
}
```

**Note :** Above code is not tested i have shared logic. `I have used this code to change font in Invoice PDF` you need to test with plugin/Prefrance.

I hope it helps!

Comment: using plugin way i tried but not working my folder structure is   PdfShipment/ShipmentChange/etc/di.xml                   PdfShipmemt/Shipment/Model/Order/PdfAbstractPdf.php        PdfShipment/Shipment/Plugin/AddFontToPdf.php

Comment: is it working with prefrance way?

Comment: Not working Preference way

Comment: In the preference way shipment.php file also overriding right?  but your mention in di.xml file    <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment" type="Namespace\Modulename\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment"/>
</config> thats why i am asking please tell me detailed explanation    so default shipment.php file also overriding or not ?

Comment: Using the preference way you can override shipment.php

Comment: i have a error config does not exisit

Comment: please tell me it showing config does not exisist

Comment: you get this error because you define the wrong config in xml use below

Comment: <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"><preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment" type="Namespace\Modulename\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment"/>
</config>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93178/discussion-between-parshuram-and-chirag-patel).

Comment: Still not working i posted code also how to do that?

Comment: I have already done PDF invoice i am asking default shipment PDF font family how to do that @Chirag Patel?