# How to change shipment PDF font style in Magento 2.2.7

Tags: magento2, pdf, preference

I am working on Magento 2.2.7 &
need to change font style of shipment pdf
i want to achieve that using preference way of di.xml file how to do that.
which files,function i have to override ?

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273051/how-to-override-default-shipment-pdf-styling-file-in-magento2-2-7

Answer (score 1):

You need to do following things.

1. create `di.xml` file into your custom extension at following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\adminhtml\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment" />
</config>
```

2. now create the `Shipment.php` file at the following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Order\Pdf;

class Shipment extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment
{
    public function getPdf($shipments = [])
    {
        // DO YOUR LOGIC HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man . it worked. multilevel inheritance  .  :)

Comment: If answer help you, upvote and accept as solution. So it will help other in community.

Comment: already done bro,please upvote the question xD